# CWE-681: Avoid numerical data corruption during incompatible mutation in Java

Tags: java, precision

I am getting an error called "Avoid numerical data corruption during incompatible mutation" according to CISQ standard and CAST scan tools. Below is the sample code. Any idea how to avoid this??

```
 public int getage() {
      return (int) ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(getdob(), LocalDate.now());
}
```

`I tried using JAVA 8 toIntExact of java.Math.toIntExact but I am not sure how different is this.`

```
return toIntExact(ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(LocalDate.of(2014,1, 1), LocalDate.now()));
```

Comment: Practically, unless you are comparing dates 2 billion years in the past or the future, this isn't an actual issue. If you must, use `toIntExact`, but otherwise just suppress it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expressed by @AndyTurner in the comment, the problem is in the cast from `long` to `int`, which could result in an erroneous calculation.

Possible workarounds are changing the return type to `long`, which could lead to just moving the cast in a different place, or using `toIntExact`.

The different with a plain old cast is that, if the `long` does not actually fit into an `int`, `toIntExact` raises a `ArithmeticException`